# Error:Could not find com.android.tools:common:25.2.3

Tags: android-studio

Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar
    https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.pom
    https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar
Required by:
    :BucketList:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3
    :BucketList:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:25.2.3
    :BucketList:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:25.2.3
    :BucketList:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:25.2.3
    :BucketList:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:25.2.3
    :BucketList:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:25.2.3
    :BucketList:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:dvlib:25.2.3
    :BucketList:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:repository:25.2.3

Comment: please can you help me fix the errors

Comment: Can you send your build.gradle code? It's almost impossible to figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: Error:(27, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_7gxirh8tgv2t2znvmsjbaw9mb$_run_closure3@53b17119] on root project 'BucketList' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\BucketList\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: That is the error i now get and leads me to this

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1'

        
    }
}
plugins {
    id "me.tatarka.retrolambda" version "3.4.0"
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
}

Comment: Are you using cordova?

Answer (score 0):

There're some problems with dependencies that has been deleted from jCenter (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347#comment30). Google is working on restoring those that were deleted incorrectly.

You can either wait till they restore artifacts or try to upgrade dependencies in your project - but it looks like those are quite outdated, so getting them up-to-date will require some effort.

---

**Update:**

Adding

```
maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools" }
```

to repositories should fix the problem temporary, until it gets fixed by Google/JCenter.

---

**Update2:**

Problem solved by Google + JCenter, no need to work-around anymore